# capturing multiple groups of items in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list in python.  Assume the name of the list is `record`.

I know `record[0]` gives me the first record and
I know `record[3:5]` gives me the third and forth record.

what if I need the first `record[0]` and `record[12:15]` and `record[35:39]` in the same list?

Thanks!

Update #1: Rephrase.

I have this list with 120 elements.  This list represents a denormalized table.

I need to break the list apart to mutliple smaller lists so I can normalize the information.

The question above is the logic for one of the smaller lists, so I can inject them into dataframes so I can add records into a table (`df.to_sql`).
Thanks.

Comment: If there's a pattern to the gaps you can use `list[start:stop:step]` otherwise you can concatenate lists together `new_list = record[0] + record[12:15] + record[35:39]`

Comment: Actually `record[3:5]` gives the fourth and fifth elements, unless you're referring to the first element as the zero-eth element, which you aren't since you say `record[0]` gives the first element.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear.  The nomenclature is inconsistent and you failed to provide a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have long lists of subranges to extract or you want a nice looking syntax, you could define a function to get multiple sub-ranges from an array:

```
from itertools import chain

def extract(array,ranges):
    return list(chain( * (array[s:e] for s,e in ranges.items()) ))

array    = list(range(100,200))
subArray = extract(array,{ 0:1, 12:15, 35:39 })

print(subArray) # [100, 112, 113, 114, 135, 136, 137, 138]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're asking.

If you need `record[0]`, `record[12:15]` and `record[35:39]`, well, there they are. 
 Go get 'em.  What is stopping you?

Do you need those elements assembled into their own smaller list?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what your exact problem is since you  havent mentioned, but if you are trying to capture similar groups of items together but also need a list why not use a dict with a string as key and list as value. There are other ways to do this probably with functools or iter utils

**Example**

```
items = [1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,2,1,3,4,1,2,1,1]

dict_of_keys = {}

for i in items:
    if i not in dict_of_keys:
        dict_of_keys[i] = []

    dict_of_keys[i].append(i)

print(dict_of_keys)

{1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4, 4], 5: [5], 6: [6], 7: [7], 8: [8]}
```